# CSS Styling on max-width of a table and img tag

Tags: html, css, width, media

My Exact same code is working fine with the screen size < 500px and >350px on the local host. But it's not working on the live website, at the website, the width of the table is not manipulated with the screen size.
Anything?

```
@media only screen and (min-width:350px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    .card-body-content table {
        max-width: 300px!important;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .card-body-content img {
        max-width: 300px!important;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: "the width of the table is not manipulated with the screen size" do you mean to say that the width of the img is manipulated but for table it is not happening? Just trying to understand the problem better!

Comment: The problem was for both of them. Table and the Image. It's resolved now. and yes, Table width can also be manipulated acc. to width of the screen.

Comment: Good to hear that it got resolved. You can go ahead and type an answer on this question yourself and mark that as correct! That will make this question closed. :)